# How to position the image in html with inline css?

Tags: html, django-inlinecss

I am trying to position an image somewhere in particular, so I need to use "top", "left" parameters instead of just "align: center". I used the below code, but it fails to move the image anywhere on the screen, it remains constant at a place.

```
<img src="./assets/button.png" alt="button" position: absolute; width: 346px; height: 40px; left: 1041px; top: 546px;>
```

Kindly help solve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this

```
<img src="./assets/button.png" alt="button" style="position: absolute; width: 346px; height: 40px; left: 1041px; top: 546px;">
```

Also as you are positioning it to a specific position you have to be sure about which it is relative to.

Suppose you want it relative to a div. Make that div's style like this

```
<div style="position: relative;">
// other codes here
</div>
```

Comment: By using relative position can I fix an image somewhere, say at the bottom of the page, even if there is no other content in the page?

Comment: By default abything is automatically relative to the body. So if you do not have anything ang you make the element absolute and give bottom: 0. then it will position it to the bottom

Comment: Oh great. I got it now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this .
Put all the css properties in the style

```
<img 
    src="./assets/button.png"
    alt="button"
    style="position:absolute; width:346px; height:40px; left:1041px; top:546px;"
>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're missing the "style" attribute, otherwise your code should run properly.